# Add version number to document from file

Tags: counters, input, external-files

I have been going crazy looking for a solution. Essentially, I need to add the version number of the document somewhere on the title page. What I want to do is have a file such as `version.tex` which contains a build number (such as 23) and everytime the `pdf` is generated, the counter is read from the file, increased, and stored back into it. This way the document number increases and I can keep track of the different versions. So, as an example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
% Initialize the counter
\newcounter{versionNumber}
% Set it to the current value THIS FAILS
\setcounter{versionNumber}{\input{version.tex}}
%Increase by one
\stepcounter{versionNumber}
% Write to the file the new number
% MISSING


\begin{document}

Version of the document: \theVersionNumber

\end{document}
```

I have looked into the `gitinfo2` package but it seems overly complicated. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Who does update `version.tex`? You?

Comment: Yes. When I call the stepcounter, I write it back to the file, effectively overwriting the previous value

Comment: There are easier approaches than this

Comment: Doesn't sound senseful. The version number would increase with every compilation - regardless if something changed. If you want an info in the pdf better add the time and the date.

Answer (score 6):

As Ulrike Fischer said: The counter would be incremented each compilation time, which is basically useless. Compilation will work even for an unchanged version, which should have the some version number then.

However, this is the feature as requested:

At the beginning of the document the counter is increased and at the end 
the current value is stored to the `.aux` file (`\@auxout`). Since this file is readin before `\begin{document}` acts, there is already some counter value in `versionNumber`, so `\stepcounter` can act.

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
% Initialize the counter
\newcounter{versionNumber}



\makeatletter 
% At the end write the current value back to the `.aux` file
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\setcounter{versionNumber}{\number\value{versionNumber}}%
  }%
}

\makeatother
% Step the counter at the beginning
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \stepcounter{versionNumber}
}



\begin{document}

Version of the document: \theversionNumber

\end{document}
```

**Edit** Another approach

Use another external file, which is updated by a true version software for example and low level `\readin` command, which stores the line into a macro, say `\versioninfo`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand{\versionfilename}{\jobname.vers}

\newwrite\versionfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\openin\versionfile=\versionfilename
  \read\versionfile to \versioninfo % \versioninfo is the macro containing the text line
\immediate\closein\versionfile% 
}





\begin{document}

Version of the document: \versioninfo

\end{document}
```

`\jobname.vers` contains for example this line

```
42 Gandalf 04/22/2015 16:03
```

[image]

Comment: The most simple thing is to use `\input{\jobname.vers}` ;-)

Comment: Hello! Is there any way that the counter has the appearence 1.1.x instead of simply Version 1, 2....n ?

Answer (score 3):

I realize that I am a bit late, but I was asking myself the exact same question and found a neat little package: [mversion](https://ctan.org/pkg/mversion?lang=en).

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mversion} %Provides version with build number.
\setVersion{0.1} %Sets the "official" version number.
\increaseBuild %Increases the build number at each build.

\begin{document}

\title{My Document Title}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{\today \\ v\version} %using the version number in the date for example
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty} %Removes page number

\end{document}
```

The "real" version number is set statically, but the build number is generated dynamically. If you want to "reset" the counter, the package creates a simple *version.dat* file in the build directory which can be manually edited. Now about putting the version number in a separate file. For large/complex documents, I put all my document settings in a TeX file such as *DocSettings.tex* and import them in my main file.

**Modified MWE:**

*DocSettings.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mversion} %Provides version with build number.
\setVersion{0.1} %Sets the "official" version number.
\increaseBuild %Increases the build number at each build.
```

*Main.tex*

```
\input{DocSettings}

\begin{document}

\title{My Document Title}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{\today \\ v\version}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty} %Removes page number

\end{document}
```

[image: 2]]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print different value from each run of TeX, then you need to do: 1) read the value from file, 2) add the value, 3) save the value to the file. This can be done by elementary TeX tools (i.e. TeX primitives plus common macros) by this code:

```
%% 0) declaration:
\newread\verfilein \newwrite\verfileout  \newcount\vernum

%% 1) reading the file:
\openin\verfilein=version.txt
\ifeof\verfilein \def\tmp{0}\else \read\verfilein to\tmp \fi
\closein\verfilein
\vernum=\tmp

%% 2) adding +1
\advance\vernum by1
\edef\thevernum{\the\vernum}

%% 3) saving the value to the file:
\immediate\openout\verfileout=version.txt
\immediate\write\verfileout{\the\vernum}
\immediate\closeout\verfileout

%% 4) using the value:

This document has the version \thevernum.
```