# Counter for version of document

Tags: counters

I am trying to create a version counter of the document, to indicate which version the user is reading. Based on this answer: 
[Add version number to document from file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239958/add-version-number-to-document-from-file) I managed to create this counter. However, I want to change the appearence of this counter from Version 1, 2, ...n to Version 1.1.1, 1.1.2, ... 1.1.n

Can anyone help me please?

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}

\newcounter{versionNumber}



\makeatletter 
% At the end write the current value back to the `.aux` file
\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\setcounter{versionNumber}{\number\value{versionNumber}}%
}%
}

\makeatother
% Step the counter at the beginning
\AtBeginDocument{%
\stepcounter{versionNumber}
}

\begin{document}

 This is the version \theversionNumber.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: using the aux file to hold the version number is very fragile lots of build scripts will do a a make clean and delete it, or if you get an error in the document the aux file may not be re-written cleanly or may need to be deleted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle any other suggestion instead of auxout ?

Comment: I would just have `\newcommand\theversionnumber{1.1.8}` in the document and arrange the editor to update it on each save or (better) have the document in a version control system and get the version number from that. Apart from anything else you want to count _edits- not how many times an unedited document has been run through latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you show me the options you just mentioned based on my MWE please?

Comment: the details depend on the editor you use for the first suggestion (I use emacs) or the version control system you use (there are latex packages to get identifiers from svn or git for example)

Comment: You could instead write to `<your base filename>.version` file using `\newwrite\versionfile \immediate\openout\versionfile=\jobname.version \immediate\write\versionfile{...} \immediate\closeout\versionfile`, and input it using `\input{\jobname.version}`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is though. Surely `1.1.\theversionNumber` is not the answer you're looking for, so you could try `\renewcommand\theversionNumber{1.1.\arabic{versionNumber}}`?

Comment: Another issue: if you don't restrict the minor parts of the version number to let's say 0 - 9 and always use the whole range (i.e. 1.2.8 > 1.2.9 > 1.3.0 and never 1.2.8 > 1.3.0), you have to set the version manually. But if you do, a single number would do. (Of course the latter could be formated with dots.)

Comment: A version control system is the way to do this, as David says. I believe that `svn` is the best option for this, but I forget why it seemed preferable to `git`. But one or other would surely be preferable to using the `.aux`.

Comment: If you don't want to use such a system and you do want to track compilations rather than edits, I'd just add a date/time stamp.